# SAX Parser not parsing photograph tag in my xml?

Tags: android, xml, url, saxparser

I have been using SAX parser to parse an xml file which has been working fine so far but for some reason won't parse the image url in the photograph tag (I want to parse the url as a string) . Was hoping someone would know the reason? any help would be appreciated.
This is the XML:

```
<candidate>
    <name>Scott Web</name>
    <office>Vice President (Academic Affairs)</office>
    <photograph>
        http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/elections/ScottWeb.jpg
    </photograph>
    <promises>
       <promise>University 2.0!</promise>
       <promise>Poducation!</promise>
       <promise>Lectures as tweets!</promise>
       <promise>Personal Tutors on Skype</promise>
       <promise>Grades on IM!</promise>
       <promise>Feedback HD</promise>
       <promise>360-degree learning portal</promise>
    </promises>
    <statement>I have made it my mission to ensure that this university gets an upgrade and defrag. Lectures and tutorials in the 21st century need to be on-line and interactive.  Vote for the future: vote for Scott Web!</statement>
</candidate>
```

and this is the code for my SAX parser:

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
String elementValue = "";
Boolean elementOn = false;
Boolean inPromises = false;
public static XMLGettersSetters data = null;

public static ArrayList<XMLGettersSetters> candList = new ArrayList<XMLGettersSetters>();

public static ArrayList<XMLGettersSetters> getCandList() {
    return candList;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    elementOn = true;
    if (localName.equals("candidate"))
    {
        data = new XMLGettersSetters();
    } else if (localName.equals("promises")) {

       inPromises = true;
     }
    }

/**
 * This will be called when the tags of the XML end.
 **/
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    elementOn = false;
    /**
     * Sets the values after retrieving the values from the XML tags
     * */
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
        data.setName(elementValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("office"))
        data.setOffice(elementValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("photograph"))
        data.setPhotograph(elementValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("promise")) {
       if(inPromises){
        data.setPromise(elementValue);
       }
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("statement"))
        data.setStatement(elementValue);
    else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("candidate"))
        candList.add(data);
}
/**
 * This is called to get the tags value
 **/
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if (elementOn) {
        elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        elementOn = false;
    }
}
```

and more:

```
public class XMLGettersSetters {
  private String name = null;
  private String office = null;
  private String photograph = null;
  private ArrayList<String> promise = new ArrayList<String>();
  private String statement = null;
  private String promises = null;

public XMLGettersSetters() {

}

public XMLGettersSetters(String name, String office, String photograph, String promises, String statement) {
    this.name = name;
    this.office = office;
    this.photograph = photograph;
    this.promises = promises;
    this.statement = statement;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name=name;
    Log.i("This is the name:", name);
}

public String getOffice() {
    return office;
}
public void setOffice(String office) {
    this.office=office;
    Log.i("This is the office:", office);
}

public String getPhotograph() {
    return photograph;
}
public void setPhotograph(String photograph) {
    this.photograph=photograph.trim();
    Log.i("This is the photo url:", photograph);
}

public ArrayList<String> getPromise() {
    return promise;
}
public void setPromise(String promise) {
    this.promise.add(promise);
    Log.i("This is the promise:", promise);
}

public String getStatement() {
    return statement;
}
public void setStatement(String statement) {
    this.statement=statement;
    Log.i("This is the statement:", statement);
}

public String getPromises() {
    return promises;
}

public void setPromises(String promises) {
    this.promises = promises;
}
```

}

Comment: when you `Log.i("This is the photo url:", photograph);` what prints in the `Logcat`?

Comment: Nothing right now in the LogCat. shows in the logCat for name, office etc. but not for photo

Comment: it prints other tags like `name`,`office`..?

Comment: Try putting the url in a `<![CDATA[http://the.url/here]]>`

Comment: Also, the difference is that in your photograph tag you have: `\n\thttp://the.url/\n` whereas in the other tags you simply have `Scott Web` and `Vice President`.  Try removing the new lines and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your characters() method appears to be expecting the whole of a text node to be delivered in a single call. There's no guarantee that this will happen, and it looks to me as if your particular SAX parser is splitting the text on newline boundaries, which it is perfectly entitled to do. This would mean that the content you get is the content after the last newline. You need to buffer up the data passed in successive calls on characters(), and process it in the call on endElement().

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have been working on that using a StringBuilder but that doesn't seem to be working either. Is that the right way to go about it?